# ROR + JS + Loading of Jquery file multiple times

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

In my rails project, I am facing some strange issue like loading of JavaScript file multiple times. I am not understanding what's wrong with code or implementation that it is loading multiple times. 
And I also find Create page also loads multiple times. I think it also affect the performance of application.

Here is the image from firebug for viewing the list of JavaScript file.
File name = jquery-1.8.3

[image]

Thanks in advance. ...

Comment: You're going to have to show us some code.

Comment: It is simply add to /assets/javascript/application.js file only once.

Comment: Ok, so this is still unanswered. How about some more details? Rails version, Ruby version, used gems, etc?